# Testing Silverlight splashscreen

Tags: silverlight, splash-screen

I have created a splashscreen in Silverlight, but my project loads so quickly that I never have a chance to test it.  How should I go about ensuring it is working?

Comment: Add a delay when the splashscreen appears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to add a call to `Thread.Sleep()` in your `App.Startup` event handler, before you assign to `RootVisual`. Your splash screen will stay up for at least as long as you sleep for.

Comment: This works great for a static splash, but I have a dynamic that handles onSourceDownloadProgressChanged.  I solved this the way I am needing it by attaching a 30 MB file to my project and marking it as content.  Your approach works too (just for static splash screens howeveR) so I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: @Nissan Fan -- Hmm, my splashscreen also handles `onSourceDownloadProgressChanged`, and with a sleep thrown in there it still shows the progress for me (VS 2010, Cassini Server and IE8). Granted, it shows it very chunky, it will go from 10% to 96% and stay at 96% for a long time, then complete.

Comment: Adding a big file is another common way of doing this too.